# Preciso enviar os dados do formulário para o meu arquivo php. Mas eu não consigo fazer funcionar, estou fazendo errado? Alguém poderia me ajudar

Tags: php, javascript, html

```js
<?php $pagina = "user/"; ?>
   
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form-Cadastrar").submit(function() {
        var pag = "<?= $pagina ?>";
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: pag + "/inserir.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,

            success: function(mensagem) {

                $('#mensagem').removeClass()

                if (mensagem == 'Cadastrado com Sucesso!!') {

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.href =
                            "user.php";
                    }, 2099);

                } else {

                    $('#mensagem').addClass('text-danger text-uppercase')
                }

                $('#mensagem').text(mensagem)

            },


            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            xhr: function() { // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) { // Avalia se tem suporte a propriedade upload
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function() {
                        /* faz alguma coisa durante o progresso do upload */
                    }, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Register</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" id="form-Cadastrar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Ex.:">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="mode">Mode:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mode" placeholder="Ex.:">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="address">Address:</label>
                  <input type="address" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cordenates">Coordinates:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cordenates" placeholder="Ex.:">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button name="btn-cad" id="btn-cad" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia, acredito que se adicionar o name nos inputs e na página obter os valores por meio do $_POST['nome_do_campo'] vc consiga os valores.

Comment: Bom dia, o código não está funcionando, quando clico em Cadastrar não acontece nada.

Comment: Acredito que agora eu entendi mais, no seu JS está que a ação será executada quando o formulário receber um submit, mas o botão que faria isso não é do tipo submit, tente adicionar, no botão submit, "type='submit'" pra ver se algo muda. Além disso, o conteúdo do script que espera o submit do formulário talvez precise estar dentro de $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: Fiz a alteração do submit mas não funcionou, to quebrando a cabeça tem 2 dias não sei o que pode ser, não consigo mais pensar.

Comment: Tenta adicionar a função dentro do $(document).ready(function() { $("#form-Cadastrar").submit(function() {$("#form-Cadastrar").submit(function() { #resto do código } }); e mantém o submit no formulário

Comment: Ou então, ao invés de esperar o submit do formulário, cria uma função que vai ser chamada ao clicar no botão Cadastrar e lá vc dá o submit

Comment: Verifica tbm se o js foi adicionado corretamente

Comment: Realmente não funciona, não sei o que esta acontecendo, vc poderia postar uma resposta de como ficaria o código por favor já com os js add?

Comment: Um amigo me ajudou a resolver, o formulário estava fechado acima do botão! Obrigado pelas respostas.

Answer (score -4):

Mostra um exemplo de como eu uso

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.form').submit(function(){
            $('.loading').html("<img src='loading.gif' width='45'>");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'controlers/cadastro_users.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('.form').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $('.mostrar').html(data);
                    $('.loading').hide();
                    $('.form')[0].reset();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

no html

```html
          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only">Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                </div> <!-- end .form-group -->

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div> <!-- end .form-group -->

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="subject" class="sr-only">Assunto</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
                </div> <!-- end .form-group -->
              </div> <!-- end .form> .row> .col-md-4 -->
              
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="message" class="sr-only">msg</label>
                  <textarea name="message" name="msg" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                </div> <!-- end .form-group -->
              </div>
            </div> <!-- end .form> .row -->

            <button class="btn btn-default contact-submit custom-btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>
            <div class="loading" style="float: left;margin-left:20px;"></div>
          </form> <!-- end .form --> 
          
          <div class="mostrar"></div>
```

Já no cadastro_users.php

```html
if($_POST){
    if(empty($_POST['nome']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['assunto']) || empty($_POST['msg'])){
        echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){swal("Ops...","Preencha todos os campos obrigatórios!","warning");});</script>';
    } else {
    
          //INICIO GERANDO VARIÁVEIS DO USUARIO.
        $Nome         = $_POST['nome'];
        $Email     = $_POST['email'];
        $Assunto        = $_POST['assunto'];
        $Msg     = $_POST['msg'];
        $Status        = 1;
        $DataRegistro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
        
        //Não esquece do PHPMAILER
include_once "../phpmailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

                                $mail = new PHPMailer;
            
                                $mail->isSMTP();
                                $mail->Host = 'mail.meusite.com.br';
                                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                                $mail->Username = 'contato@meusite.com.br';
                                $mail->Password = '+qyq4Zqs3aF3X?FQ';
                                $mail->Port = 587;
            
                                $mail->setFrom('contato@meusite.com.br', 'Meu Site');
                                $mail->addAddress(DBEscape($Email));
            
                                $mail->isHTML(true);
            
                                $mail->Subject = $Assunto;
                                $mail->Body    =  "<h3>DETALHES DA Mensagem: </h3>
                                                   <br />
                                                   <strong>Nome:</strong>     ".$Nome."<br />
                                                   <strong>E-mail:</strong>   ".$Email."<br />
                                                   <strong>Assunto:</strong> ".$Assunto."<br />
                                                   <strong>Data:</strong>    ".$horario."<br />
                                                   <strong>Mensagem:</strong> ".$Msg."<br />

                                $mail->AltBody = "MeuSite";
                                
                                if(!$mail->send()) {
                                    //echo 'Não foi possível enviar a mensagem.<br>';
                                    //echo 'Erro: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                    echo'<script>$(document).ready(function(){swal("Ops '.utf8_encode($Nome).'...","Houve um erro ao enviar, tente novamente!", "error");});</script>';
                                } else {
                                    //echo 'Mensagem enviada.';
                                    echo'<script>$(document).ready(function(){swal("Sucesso '.utf8_encode($Nome).'...", "Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!!", "success")});</script>';
                                }
                            }
```

Só fazer conforme tu precisa ai...